# Use ConcurrentHashMap to replace HazelCast IMap with locking

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, hazelcast, spring-rabbit

Removing HazelCast from an application that no longer needs distributed caching.
However I still need to keep the synchronized access to a Map similar to IMap.
I first wanted to replace IMap with Map and ConcurrentHashMap.

Now the collection is just a simple Java Map, but I still need to control asynchronous read/write to it.
Would a ConcurrentHashMap be enough to solve this, or do I need other locking solutions/mechanism.

The application is using RabbitMQ, with 3 Queues.
With HazelCast I had a IMap with domain objects, that i performed locking on in each MQ thread accessing it.

During Initialization of a Batch job, it creates new domain objects, and places it on the Map.
At the end of the Initialization it sends out a request on 3 different message queues for each object in the Map.

Only 1 MQ thread should be able to get an object from the Map, update it, and put it back on the Map.
Can ConcurrentHashMap handle that, I do I need to implement some locking/unlocking between the Map.get and Map.put?

With HazelCast this was done with locking on the Map.

```
IMap<Long, MyObject> myCollection;

public void processMessage1(final MyResponse1 reponse) { // MQ-Thread1
    final Long myObjectId = response.getObjectId();
    myCollection.lock(myObjectId);
    try {
        final MyObject myObject = myCollection.get(myObjectId);
        updateMyObject(myObject, response);
        myCollection.put(myObjectId, myObject)
        if (myObject.isCompleted()) {
            repository.save(myObject);
        }
    } finally {
        myCollection.unlock(myObjectId);
    }
}

public void processMessage2(final MyResponse2 reponse) { // MQ-Thread2
    // Similar with locking as processMessage1
}

public void processMessage3(final MyResponse3 reponse) { // MQ-Thread3
    // Similar with locking as processMessage1
}
```

How my code is now when changed HazelCast and IMap locking to ConcurrentHashMap.

```
@Data
@Component
public class MyCache {
    private final Map<Long, Producer> producers = new HashMap<>();
    private final ConcurrentMap<Long, Customer> customers = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
}

@Service
public class CustomerService {

    private final MyCache myCache;

    private final StorageService storageService;

    public CustomerService(final MyCache myCache, final StorageService storageService) {
        this.myCache = myCache;
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @Transaction
    public void startProcessingAll() {
        getProducers();
        deleteCustomers();
        myCache.getProducers().keySet().forEach(id -> startProcessingProducer(id));
    }

    private void startProcessingProducer(Long producerId) {
        log.info("Started processing for producerId={}", producerId);
        initialize(producerId);
    }

    private void initialize(Long producerId) {
        log.info("Initialize start {}", producerId);
        final Customer customer = new Customer();
        sendRabbitMq1(producerId);
        sendRabbitMq2(producerId);
        sendRabbitMq3(producerId);

        myCache.getCustomers().put(producerId, customer);
        log.info("Initialize end {}", producerId);
    }

    private void deleteCustomers() {
        storageService.deleteCustomers();
    }

}

@Service
public class MessageService {

    private final MyCache myCache;

    private final StorageService storageService;

    public MessageService(final MyCache myCache, final StorageService storageService) {
        this.myCache = myCache;
        this.storageService = storageService;
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public Consumer<MyResponse1> response1() {
        return this::processResponse1;
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public Consumer<MyResponse2> response2() {
        return this::processResponse2;
    }

    @Bean
    @Transactional
    public Consumer<MyResponse3> response3() {
        return this::processResponse3;
    }

    private void processResponse1(final MyResponse1 response) {
        myCache.getCustomers().computeIfPresent(response.getProducerId(),
            (producerId, customer) -> updateFromResponse1(response, customer));
    }

    private Customer updateFromResponse1(final MyResponse1 response, final Customer customer) {
        log.debug("Got Response 1 {}", response);
        // Updating Customer with Response
        process(customer, storageService::saveCustomer);
        return customer;
    }

    public void process(final Customer customer, final Consumer<Customer> customerUpdateCallback) {
        // Processing Customer
        customerUpdateCallback.accept(customer);
    }

}

@Service
public class StorageService {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public StorageService(final CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public void saveCustomer(final Customer customer) {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

    public void deleteCustomer() {
        customerRepository.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

Comment: By the way… Rather than Map & ConcurrentHashMap, you may want [*ConcurrentMap*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) & ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*ConcurrentHashMap* can address key locking using one of the following method:

- [compute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#compute(K,java.util.function.BiFunction)) if you need to manage both adding and updating new objects to the map
- [computeIfPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfPresent(java.lang.Object,java.util.function.BiFunction)) if only update is required.

The key information is that the javadoc states:

> The entire method invocation is performed atomically. The supplied function is invoked exactly once per invocation of this method.

If we adapt your code sample to work for update with a ConcurrentHashMap, it would give something like this:

```java
final Map<Long, MyObject> myCollection = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void processMessage1(final MyResponse1 reponse) { // MQ-Thread1
    final Long myObjectId = response.getObjectId();
    myCollection.computeIfPresent(myObjectId, (key, oldValue) -> {
        var newValue = updateMyObject(oldValue, response);
        if (newValue.isCompleted()) {
            repository.save(newValue);
        }
        return newValue;
    });
}
```

Comment: I am not getting the expected behaviour using ConcurrentHashMap and computeIfPresent.  I get 1, only 1 access to computeIfPresent, then the applications hangs. Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I now found the reason, but not know why. My applications deletes all Customers from database before processing. Then for each Customer in the Map, it computes and  save it to the database. If I prior to running the application just deletes the content of the database, it works fine, and does not hang.

Comment: I suspect it is a problem with the outer Transaction not being used within the computeIfPresent.

Comment: If I move the repository.save out of the computeIfPresent, only then it works.

Comment: Mmh... This is strange. That looks like a dead-lock, but I do not understand what could cause it.  Note that some (most ?) database framework don't support multi-threaded transactions, so if you use transactions, ensure each is started, executed and terminated on a single thread.

Comment: Before without computeIfPresent it would delete from database prior to sending the RabbitMQ messages. Then when receiving the RabbitMQ responses it would be in a different thread and process and save to database. This flow with computeIfPresent are still within the same different threads, so why would it not work now I cannot find out. I think I need to create a new Question to find that out.

Comment: I have verified it is the same thread outside and inside the computeIfPresent, but repository.save only works outside of it.